# chrome.scripting.executeScript not working in my manifest v3 Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension where I call

```
function doScript(window) {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: window.tabs[0].id},
      files: ['myscript.js'],
    });
}
```

myscript.js simply has

```
alert("Made it")
```

but I get no alert in my tab.

If I change the tabId to something random like 123

```
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: 123},
      files: ['myscript.js'],
    });
```

then I get an error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: No tab with id: 123"

So it looks like my tabId is right, but for some reason myscript.js is not triggering an alert.

If I mess up the script name like this

```
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: window.tabs[0].id}},
      files: ['ttttttttttt.js'],
    });
```

I get "runtime.lastError: Could not load file: 'ttttttttttt.js'."

I tried looking through the console logs and the only thing I see is this error upon clicking but it looks like a red herring.

"Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host."
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals-extension/issues/54

Here is my manifest

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "pokemon bokemon",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.3.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "32": "icon32.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "scripting",
        "activeTab",
        "cookies"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

EDIT: Apparently it's a bug in chrome/manifest v3. Opened a bug here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1191971

Comment: The code is fine assuming `window` is produced by chrome.windows API and its first tab is a web tab, not an empty newtab or a browser UI or devtools. It could be also a bug in Chrome so try on a different simpler site like https://www.example.com/

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for confirming. It is created via `chrome.windows.create({
    url: url,
    type: 'popup',
  }, doScript);`

Comment: remember to give proper permissions like "permissions": ["scripting"] in your manifest file

Comment: Also here didn't work

Answer (score 6):

I also encountered the same problem, and I share my experience as follows.

If you use `chrome.windows.create` to create a new tab(panel, popup,...) and then call `chrome.scripting.executeScript` in the new one. Unfortunately, it will not work.

for example

```
// popup.js
const targetURL = 'templates/main.html'
chrome.windows.create(
  {
    focused: true,
    url: targetURL,
    type: 'popup',
  },
  (subWindow) => {
  }
)
// But you can put the ``chrome.scripting.executeScript``here, which will be fine.
chrome.scripting.executeScript({})
```

does not work in `templates/main.html`

```html
<script>
// templates/main.html

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}).then(([tab]) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript(
    {
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      files: ['myscript.js'],
      // function: () => {}, // files or function, both do not work.
    })
})
</script>
```

---

If you want to communicate with each other, you can try.

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(myTabID, {event: 'myTest'}, ({msg, other})=>{
  console.log(msg) // hello
  console.log(other) // test
})

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((media, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (media.event === 'myTest') {
    sendResponse({msg:"hello", other:"test"})
  }
})
```

### Supplement for sendMessage & onMessage

- [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-sendMessage)
- [chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#example-content-msg)

If you need a working example, you can refer to one of my repositories.

> https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/tree/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info

[image]

Click the button, and the following log will show some information from the tabs.

Suggested order for your reading:

two parts

1. sendMessage

   1. [manifest.json -> popup.html](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/manifest.json#L21)
   2. [popup.html -> popup.js](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/templates/popup.html#L6)
   3. [popup.js -> main.html](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/static/js/src/popup.js#L4)
   4. [main.html -> main.js](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/templates/main.html#L6)
   5. [main.js: chrome.tabs.sendMessage](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/static/js/src/main.js#L7-L11)
2. onMessage

   - [manifest.json content_scripts: scripting/thumbnail.js](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/manifest.json#L17)
   - [thumbnail.js: onMessage](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/7f1e731/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/static/js/src/scripting/thumbnail.js#L12-L30)

---

#### Supplement

- handle the error from `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`: When you add callback parameters, it will return `undefined`.
  if you want to handle the error by yourself, you should omit this parameter, which will return the `Promise`. [example](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/chrome/blob/521d72cf266ba2fe2a5828b1ee1d5a5b7a4f0474/tutorials/extensions/tabs-info/static/js/src/main.js#L20-L30)

Comment: What's the point of sending a message to a tab? How does the tab intercept this message and where?

Comment: Hi @vdegenne , I have updated my answer. I hope it helps you.
Honestly, I don't know if I'm doing the right thing. The supplement is not directly related to the question, but indirectly, like taking money to a vending machine to buy a drink, but the drink doesn't come out, and asking how to solve the problem. For most consumers, all they care about is getting their drinks, and fixing the vending machine is not their concern. This supplement is just another way to communicate with the tab.  If all you care about is fixing the vending machine, please ignore the supplement; thanks.

Comment: @Carson your sample code is throwing following error, could you please let me know what is the problem?

Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
Context
templates/main.html
Stack Trace
templates/main.html:0 (anonymous function)

Comment: Hi @Aditya , This message is caused by `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`
If you want to handle this message manually, you can make `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` return as the promise format (omitting the `callback` parameters)
and then you can add the `catch` function to handle the error message.

Comment: I have updated the answer. See the supplement for the issue: `handle the error from chrome.tabs.sendMessage` (`Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`)

Comment: Why `If you use chrome.windows.create to create a new tab(panel, popup,...) and then call chrome.scripting.executeScript in the new one. Unfortunately, it will not work.`?

Answer (score 6):

[For Manifest v3]

You can also execute a function directly instead of passing a file:

Add this line in manifest.json:

`"permissions": ["scripting"]`

```js
 let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })

 // Execute script in the current tab
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: (items) => {
      Object.keys(items).forEach((key) => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, items[key])
      })
    },
    args: [items] // pass any parameters to function
  })
```

Comment: its target: { tabId: tab.id }, not target: { tabId: tab.Id },

Answer (score 2):

Manifest version 3
Use this:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    console.log(tabs[0].url);
    console.log(tabs[0].id);
    my_tabid=tabs[0].id;
}); 
alert(my_tabid);

chrome.scripting.executeScript(
{
    target: {tabId: my_tabid},
    files: ['myscript.js'],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that the `chrome.scripting.executeScript` part is executed too fast.

For instance it starts working if you add a timer of 2 seconds:

```
const timer = ms => {
    function randn_bm(middle_number) {
        let u = 0, v = 0;
        while(u === 0) u = Math.random(); //Converting [0,1) to (0,1)
        while(v === 0) v = Math.random();
        let num = Math.sqrt( -2.0 * Math.log( u ) ) * Math.cos( 2.0 * Math.PI * v );
        num = num / 10.0 + 0.5; // Translate to 0 -> 1
        if (num > 1 || num < 0) return randn_bm() // resample between 0 and 1
        return num * 2 * middle_number
      }
      ms=randn_bm(ms);
      console.log(ms)
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  }
```

You can use this timer like so: `await timer(2000)`

For sure an async behaviour would be preferable but so you understand why this happens: the script is executed before the new tab completely opened. Therefore the function is never executed.

Comment: that line is not correct, something should be passed right there `return randn_bm()`