# `chrome.scripting.exectuteScript` is not working - Chrome Extensions - Manivest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am pretty new in the Chrome Extensions field.

I am trying to build an extension to visit some websites and collect information from their HTML.

I am having a hard time getting `chrome.scripting.executeScript` working properly.

### Source Code

#### manifest.json

```json
{
    "name": "Scraper",
    "description": "Simple Extension to Scrape Websites, and Push Them to ConnectionSphere for Data Enrichment",
    "version": "2.0",
    "permissions": ["storage", "webRequest", "scripting", "declarativeContent", "activeTab", "tabs", "downloads", "*://*/*", "http://connectionsphere.com:80/*", "http://connectionsphere.com/api1.0/emails/verify.json"],
    "host_permissions": [ "https://www.amazon.com/*", "https://connectionsphere.com/*", "https://github.com/*" ],
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
      "48": "/48.png",
      "128": "/128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "48": "/48.png",
            "128": "/128.png"
        }
    }
}
```

#### popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Scraper</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="notify-wrapper">
            <div id="notify-header">
            <h1>Scraper!</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="notify-containers">
            <div class="login-form">
                <input type="button" id="start" name="start" value="Start" />
                <p id="text" name="text"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### popup.js

```js
'use strict';

let text = document.getElementById('text');

function upload_page() {
alert('b');
    document.body.innerHTML = 'hola';
    return document.title;
}

start.onclick = function() {
    let page_url_value = 'https://github.com/';
    text.innerHTML = 'Scraping page...';
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, async function(tabs) {
        // get the tab id
        var tab_id = tabs[0].id;
        // go to the page
        chrome.tabs.update({url: page_url_value});
        // fired when tab is updated
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function openPage(tabID, changeInfo) {
            // tab has finished loading
            if(tab_id == tabID && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
                // remove tab onUpdate event as it may get duplicated
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(openPage);
                // execute content script
alert('a');
                chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                    {
                        target: {tabId: tab_id, allFrames: true},
                        func: upload_page
                    }, 
                    // Get the value returned by do_login.
                    // Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#handling-results
                    (injectionResults) => {
                        for (const frameResult of injectionResults)
                            text.innerHTML = frameResult.result;
                    }
                );
            }
        });    
    });
};
```

### The Problem

When the user clicks on the "start" button of the popup, the extension visits a page and calls `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to run a function that works with the DOM of such a page. But such execution is not performed (the`alert('a')` happens, but the `alert('b')` is never executed).

If I refresh the page manually from the browser and click on the "start" button again, then the `chrome.scripting.executeScript` runs.

I researched for an answer into other posts here, but I didn't find anything.

The answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772626/chrome-scripting-executescript-not-working-in-my-manifest-v3-chrome-extension) didn't help me.

I wrote a small test-unit to show the problem I am facing.

Comment: Try debugging: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu to open devtools. BTW there's probably no need for chrome.tabs.onUpdated - try calling executeScript immediately after `await chrome.tabs.update(.....)`.

Comment: Works for me, it shows both the "a" and "b" alerts. Try removing the extension and loading it again.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I got error "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Cannot access contents of url "https://github.com/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host."

Comment: @ThomasMueller It worked after I removed and added it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I removed the extension and added it again. Thanks!